# If the boundary of $A$ in $\Bbb R^n$ has measure $0$, can the boundary of $A \setminus B$ have a measure greater than $0$ for $B \subset A$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If the boundary of $A$ in $\Bbb R^n$ has measure $0$, can the boundary of $A \setminus B$ have a measure greater than $0$?

I was wondering whether it is possible for the boundary of a region in $\Bbb R^n$ to have smaller boundary (Lebesgue measure) than a subset of itself. If we remove "pieces" from the region $A$, can the new region have a larger boundary? Intuitively, it shouldn't be possible, but I think there might be some crazy function or region that have this property.

Comment: Take $n=1, A=\mathbb R$ and $B=\mathbb  Q$. Here $m(\partial A)=0$ and $m(\partial (A\setminus B))=\infty$.

Comment: You've written $B \in A$ in the title but I suspect you wish to make it $B \subset A$. (`\subset` instead of `\in`.)

Comment: If $A=\mathbb R^n$ then the boundary of $A$ is the empty set which has measure zero, while the boundary of $A\setminus B$ is the boundary of $B$ which can have positive measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed possible, as has been pointed out in the comments. Consider $A = [0, 1]$ and $B = [0, 1] \cap \Bbb Q$. Then, $\partial A = \{0, 1\}$ has measure $0$ whereas $\partial(A \setminus B) = [0, 1]$ has measure $1$. This is easy to generalise in higher dimensions.

In fact, even intuitively, one should suspect that something like this is possible. Indeed, when you are removing things from "inside", you're creating more "holes", which would lead to more "boundary". As an analogy, if you think of a cuboid and you cut a thin slice from its interior, you actually end up with more surface area.

Comment: oh yes of course. thanks. I was only thinking of removing connected regions.